# How does Nincada evolve into Shedinja?

Tags: pokemon

*Nincada* can evolve into both *Ninjask* as well as *Shedinja*.
But under what conditions it evolves to either one of these?

Comment: Do you mean in the games? If so, this question is off-topic here. If you want to know the lore on this though (either from the games or anime or any other medium) then it's an acceptable question here.

Comment: No.I am asking in the anime series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I believe we have only seen a sort of evolution happen once and this was in the Pokemon Adventures manga.

> Shedinja first appeared when Aqua Admin Amber, having been deprived of his Pokémon after being abandoned by Archie, borrows a Nincada from his comrade Shelly, which then immediately evolves into a Ninjask, putting Wattson in quite a pinch with the incredible speed it gained by the minute. **Although the old Gym Leader eventually managed to defeat it, a Shedinja formed from the shell Ninjask shed and attacked him from behind**, sending him sinking into the ocean.

In the highlighted part, it states that the Shedinja formed from the shell of the defeated Ninjask shed. This also does explain why Shedinja is a Ghost Pokemon instead of a Flying Pokemon like Ninjask.

So my final conclusion is that in the story for a Shedinja to be created, a Ninjask has to be defeated/die.

Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shedinja_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#In_the_anime)

Comment: But the shell of a _Ninjask_ is black whereas the shell of _Shedinja_ is brown. How is that possible?

Comment: @HariNandha it is a evolution. Their form does not have to stay the same neither do their colors have to stay the same. Dont forget his original form (pre-evolution) is totaly greenish. Also the appearance of allot of pokemon seem to differ from each other. ment in the way, in the anime and the manga they might look different from the games and so on. So there is no real explaination from the appearence change except that is A evolution